# NetBeans8.2 ==> Unable to automatically import third party libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm a JAVA developer

I have recently encountered a more troubling question

There was no result after the search, so I wanted to ask questions.

That's true：

I was using NetBeans IDE 7.1.2,

The process is very good and there is almost no problem.

But because I wanted to use JAVA8, I upgraded to IDE8.2

And then there's a very difficult problem.

IDE can't automatically import third-party libraries for me.

For example, I imported an external jar inside the library.

At IDE7.1.2, he would pop a yellow light bulb.

When I click, he will remind me of something like import.

But in IDE8. 2, he just prompted me to create a new class

The problem exists only in the third party library, for example:

```
List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList ();
```

IDE will prompt me to import java.utils.List and java.utils.ArrayList

But if I import third-party packages:

```
Public class tempClass extends JavaPlugin (located in the org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin third-party Library)
```

He won't prompt me to `import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin`'s import

I was prompted to create a JavaPlugin class in the package

Thanks XD

Comment: Did you not have to register your 3rd party libraries for your Projects in NetBeans 7.1.2 through the **Ant Library Manager** or through the Project -> Properties -> Libraries? If you don't have the **Use Dedicated Folder for Storing Libraries** check marked when you created your Java Application project then chances are you'll have to register them again in NetBeans 8.2 (I think :/ ).

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.
I have Spigot-1.12.jar (third party libraries) in Project - > Properties - > Libraries. Add jar to the inside.
In fact, if I write myself
Import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
In the code
He can compile it on its own, and there will be no red line
It's just that he can't help me automatically prompt me to import this class

Comment: Oh, thank you. What you say is effective! I just looked through the attribute column, and found that what you said is really effective. Thank！